# how to use 'inline-template' in dynamic component?

Tags: vue.js, components

define a component, if add inline-template property, it can rewrite it's template.

```
<TestComponent inline-template>
// can rewrite component template
</TestComponent>
```

when use `<component :is="xx" :inline-template="true"></component>`, What does 'inline-template' do? How to rewrite?